# Reading values from SOAPHeader in PHP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm writing a piece of PHP to consume a webservice.
I'm using something like :

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://somewebservicesmx?WSDL",  array('trace' => 1));
$session = $client->SomeFuncion();
```

... and that's working fine.

But this webservice return important data on the soap headers in the first call.

I want to read those values from the header, and I have tried with simplexml_load_string, which just returns empty.
Also tried witH:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($soapLastResponse);
$value = $doc->getElementsByTagName("somenode");
$value = $value->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Which seems to work, but I wonder if there is a "correct way" to achieve this.
I wonder if there is some function that can get me a value from the header without using `DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for?

```
$soapClient->__getLastResponseHeaders();
```

It requires that `'trace'=>true` in the construction of the `SoapClient`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponseheaders.php

Edit: my confusion - recommend [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)

Comment: My $soapLastResponse variable contains the response of soapClient->__getLastResponseHeaders() already! ;) I was looking for alternatives to the use of DOMDocument()

Comment: Ahah! I would recomment SimpleXmlELement() then. http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php It's, as the name suggest, simple!